# Visual Studio (Mac) Orange window

Tags: macos, visual-studio

When opening one of my node js folders in Visual Studio for mac the window turns orange (see screenshot). Why and how to get rid of this? Im not running in debugging mode from what I can tell. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok. This was due to the settings in .vscode inherited from an external package.